# why scala in this case can't use single abstract method?

Tags: scala

i use spring boot's RedisTemplate with scala, and i write this code:

```
redisTemplate1.executePipelined(new RedisCallback[String] {
  override def doInRedis(connection: RedisConnection): String = {
    MyCode......
    null
  }
}, redisTemplate1.getValueSerializer)
```

usually, it's can be wrote like this:

```
redisTemplate1.executePipelined((connection: RedisConnection) => {
  MyCode......
  null
}, redisTemplate1.getValueSerializer)
```

and this style is running well in java:

```
redisTemplate1.executePipelined((RedisConnection conn) -> {
    MyCode......
    return null;
}, redisTemplate1.getValueSerializer());
```

but when i compile in this style with scala, i get an error, so why this happend and how can i use single abstract method in this case?

```
overloaded method value executePipelined with alternatives:
  (x$1: org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisCallback[_],x$2: org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.RedisSerializer[_])java.util.List[Object] <and>
  (x$1: org.springframework.data.redis.core.SessionCallback[_],x$2: org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.RedisSerializer[_])java.util.List[Object]
 cannot be applied to (org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisConnection => Null, org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.RedisSerializer[?0(in method syncSegmentSrc)])
    redisTemplate1.executePipelined((connection: RedisConnection) => {
```

the executePipelined function source code like this:

```
@Override
public List<Object> executePipelined(SessionCallback<?> session, @Nullable RedisSerializer<?> resultSerializer) {
    Assert.isTrue(initialized, "template not initialized; call afterPropertiesSet() before using it");
    Assert.notNull(session, "Callback object must not be null");
    RedisConnectionFactory factory = getRequiredConnectionFactory();
    // bind connection
    RedisConnectionUtils.bindConnection(factory, enableTransactionSupport);
    try {
        return execute((RedisCallback<List<Object>>) connection -> {
            connection.openPipeline();
            boolean pipelinedClosed = false;
            try {
                Object result = executeSession(session);
                if (result != null) {
                    throw new InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException(
                            "Callback cannot return a non-null value as it gets overwritten by the pipeline");
                }
                List<Object> closePipeline = connection.closePipeline();
                pipelinedClosed = true;
                return deserializeMixedResults(closePipeline, resultSerializer, hashKeySerializer, hashValueSerializer);
            } finally {
                if (!pipelinedClosed) {
                    connection.closePipeline();
                }
            }
        });
    } finally {
        RedisConnectionUtils.unbindConnection(factory);
    }
}

@Override
public List<Object> executePipelined(RedisCallback<?> action, @Nullable RedisSerializer<?> resultSerializer) {
    return execute((RedisCallback<List<Object>>) connection -> {
        connection.openPipeline();
        boolean pipelinedClosed = false;
        try {
            Object result = action.doInRedis(connection);
            if (result != null) {
                throw new InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException(
                        "Callback cannot return a non-null value as it gets overwritten by the pipeline");
            }
            List<Object> closePipeline = connection.closePipeline();
            pipelinedClosed = true;
            return deserializeMixedResults(closePipeline, resultSerializer, hashKeySerializer, hashValueSerializer);
        } finally {
            if (!pipelinedClosed) {
                connection.closePipeline();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: The sorter version is just an abbreviaton of the full one that the compiler can understand when there are no other options. In this case, I'd say that the compiler is saying that it can't expand the code to the bigger one because there are 2 ways of expanding the code and it doesn't know which one is the desired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In cases like this, it should help to specify the type explicitly:

```
redisTemplate1.executePipelined({ connection =>
  YourCode…
}: RedisCallback[String], redisTemplate1.getValueSerializer)
```

Note the type ascription `: RedisCallback[String]`.